# PUT or POST when creating and updating records at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, nested-attributes, put

I have a mobile app that accesses a server running a Rails 3.x app. The data is exchanged in JSON format.

I have a rather complicated issue, that I going to try and simplify here.

In one scenario, the mobile app posts a new **sale** record to the database which includes an update to an existing **order** record.  To achieve this as a single HTTP request, it passes the **order** record attributes update as part of the new **sale** record via nested attributes.

The Rails model for Sales includes the following:

```
attr_accessible :product_id, :order_id, :order_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order, :update_only => true
```

The Rails routings are standard.

As the http request to post the **sale** will create a new record (i.e. it does not include an existing sale_id), I use HTTP POST.

I can post a new **sale** record (without the **order** record update) just fine.

However, when I include the nested attributes to update the **order** record, I get 404 'not found'.

I *suspect* that this is because the nested update of the existing **order** includes an 'id' and therefore should actually be a PUT (to route correctly).

To help diagnose the issue, I've tried changing existing working non-nested POSTs of **sales** (that don't include an id) to be PUT requests, and in that case, it does break the functionality, and I do get a 404.  This suggests to me that the server would indeed report PUT/POST confusion as a 404.

To be clear I can successfully post updates using nested attributes in other circumstances using the same code, so I'm confident that it's not the actual attribute encoding that is the problem.

I'd appreciate thoughts on whether this could be the issue, and if so what I can do about it.

Thank you.

Comment: That's relatively old Rails issue. Check it issue for details https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2925

Comment: Thanks for that.  That's weird, and it leaves me scratching my head as to when nested attributes would actually work / be used.